# FailedToResolveConfigException Failed to resolve config path

Tags: elasticsearch

elasticsearchのバージョン1.5.1

Elasticsearchでインデックス作成時に以下のようなエラーが出ます

$ curl -XPOST localhost:9200/new_index -d @settings.json

---

エラー

nested: IndexCreationException[[new_index] failed to create index];
nested: FailedToResolveConfigException[Failed to resolve config path [products_synonyms.txt], tried file path [products_synonyms.txt], path file [/etc/elasticsearch/products_synonyms.txt], and classpath

---

settings.json

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "products_analyzer" : {
                "type" : "custom",
                "tokenizer" : "kuromoji_products_dict",
                "filter" : ["products_synonym", "lowercase"]
            }
        },
        "tokenizer" : {
            "kuromoji_products_dict" : {
              "type" : "kuromoji_tokenizer",
              "mode" : "search",
              "discard_punctuation" : "true"
            }
        },
        "filter" : {
          "products_synonym" : {
            "type" : "synonym",
            "synonyms_path" : "products_synonyms.txt"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

---

synonyms_pathがまちがっているっぽいのですが、pathはどこに設定すればいいのでしょうか？？またsynonymを定義したファイルはどこに置けばいいのでしょうか？？

ちなみにこのエラーのときにsynonymを定義したファイルは`/etc/elasticsearch/products_synonyms.txt`に置いてます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決ですが、、

`$ curl localhost:9200/_nodes?pretty`

でnode見ると、nodeが「Needle」（node名）、「Jean Grey」（node名）があった。
「Needle」があるインスタンスにproducts_synonyms.txtは配置していたが、「Jean Grey」には配置していなかった。配置後にエラー起きずインデックス作成できた。

Answer (score 1):

エラーを見る限り、

```
/etc/elasticsearch/products_synonyms.txt
```

に配置すれば一応は解決するのではないかと思っていますが、どうでしょうか。

Comment: すいません、質問内容のsynonyms_pathが間違っていたので変更しました。`/etc/elasticsearch/products_synonyms.txt`に配置して上記のエラーが出てしまいます。。

Comment: @SuzukiKeita 自分の手元では、例外が指し示しているパスにファイルを配置すると当該エラーは解消したので、仮にパスが間違っていないとすると、これ以上はわからないですね。。。

Comment: masterのnodeがあるインスタンスにファイルを配置していましたが、クラスターを組むその他のnodeがあるインスタンスにファイルを配置できていませんでした。そちらに配置したところ解決できました。